# Can't install the 'https' module in React / Webpack

Tags: reactjs, ssl, webpack, fetch

I need the `https` module for some reason reated to the SSL verification.

Here is the error message I got after compiling :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/etcetera ...'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
```

The **https** module is installed ...

The final purpose is to use this code which will disable the SSL certificate verification :

```
import https from 'https'
const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
});


    fetch(AN_API_URL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization : AN_API_KEY
        },
        agent: agent
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message))
```

Comment: "https" is a server side package for making secure http requests with nodejs. It will not work client side.

Comment: Thanks, I see.

I am looking for a solution to disable the SSL certificate verification client side (I mean within the fetch request). Can't find any option doing this. 

Any idea ?